# MFA for Azure AD Single Tenant application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have registed and app in Azure AD (AAD1) as single tenant application. the token endpoint is https://login.microsoftoline/.

I have a user existing in another AAD tenant (AAD2) and this user is Guest into my application tenant

No i want enforce MFA for this user by enabling Security defaults or conditional policy in AAD 2. Is it possible? If i register the app as mulit-tenant app in AAD 1, user is prompted for MFA

But not when App is registered as Single tenant

Answer (score 0):

What **may** be happening here is that:

- When the app is multi-tenant the user logs in to AAD2 that requires MFA
- When the app is single-tenant the user is treated a guest of AAD1 which does not require MFA

You could try setting up MFA at the app level, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa#configure-the-conditions-for-multi-factor-authentication

Comment: I was the MFA to be controlled my AAD2 and not at AAD1. Reason beign the customer users are in AAD2 and we would like them decide when they need MFA